# Parallel array assignment in Fortran90

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I need to speed up a multi-dimensional array assignment with  matrix multiplication over some indices. The original cycle is

```
  FORALL (ia=1:2,ib=1:2,ic=1:2) U(:,ia,:,ib,ic)= 
 + W(ic,ia,ib,1)*matmul(FS(:,ia,:,1),transpose(F(:,ib,:,1)))+
 + W(ic,ia,ib,2)*matmul(FS(:,ia,:,2),transpose(F(:,ib,:,2)))
```

The matrix multiplication is over the large dimension >100.
What is the best way to increase speed using OMP directives on a workstation with parallel Intel Xeon cores ? Say,

```
!$OMP DO      
  DO ic=1,2
  DO ib=1,2
  DO ia=1,2
  U(:,ia,:,ib,ic)= 
 + W(ic,ia,ib,1)*matmul(FS(:,ia,:,1),transpose(F(:,ib,:,1)))+
 + W(ic,ia,ib,2)*matmul(FS(:,ia,:,2),transpose(F(:,ib,:,2)))
  ENDDO
  ENDDO
  ENDDO
!$OMP END DO
```

Will this work or there are better alternatives ? Thank you

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Are you *really* sure you are only interested in answers using the very old and obselete Fortran 90? We have year 2021. Did you try your loop? Did you measure the performance? What was the result?

Comment: The easiest way to speed it up is to only do the matrix multiplies you actually need to do - because of the ic loop you are doing twice as many as you need

Comment: Once you have sorted out the ic loop I would look into using dgemm rather than matmul, any respectable dgemm will be threaded already so that does the parallelism for you, and I would definitely try to sort out the memory access patterns, can the arrays be reorganised so you have FS( :, :, ia, 1) and similar? But beyond that without a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)it is very difficult to say any more.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I currently run the program without any parallel instructions. It is a part of the larger code and I need to run it in quad precision.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I currently run the program without any parallel instructions. It is a part of the larger code and I need to run it in quad precision to get 20+ significant digits which is requirement.  All matrices are complex and I also need to calculate eigenvalues/eigenvectors. I used a source code of cgeev with dependencies and compiled it all together using Intel ifort with the -real_size 128 option.  I am currently running it on 28 Xeon processors workstation but in a single thread, each run takes 2-3 hours. Thanks @Ian for advise regarding FS(:,:,ia,1) array, I will try it.